# How to convert Node object to JSON?

Tags: javascript

I have code which return a single Node.

```
var items = document.querySelectorAll('ul');
return items[0];
```

How can I convert it to JSON? For me method JSON.parse() doesn't work. It takes not Node but string object.

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` takes a JavaScript object and serializes it to JSON if possible.

Comment: What node are you trying to convert? What are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: ... Because parsing parses JSON. `JSON.stringify` makes JSON. But it's not clear what you actually want to get from the unordered list as JSON.

Comment: JSON doesn't have an HTMLElementNode data type, so you can't convert it directly. If you had some specific translation in mind then you'd need to explain that.

Comment: DOM nodes contain circular references, so it's not possible to just convert it. You have build a new object with the information you want.

Comment: You can't just convert a javascript Node object into JSON as it's deeply nested and contains native DOM functions and properties. You'll have to convert this manually by just getting only properties that you require.

Comment: Hm... when I use `JSON.stringify` I get `Converting circular structure to JSON`.

Comment: @Alex: That's what several people said would happen already. You need to create a new object with only the properties you'd like (e.g. `var myObject = { id: items[0].id, title: items[0].title };`; then, convert it: `var json = JSON.stringify(myObject);`).

Comment: @Alex Because that's not what you really want to do--you want to get the *contents* of the list nodes as JSON, *probably*. You don't actually say what you want, which is why everybody is asking that.